# The iCloud photo is all black

Tags: ios, iphone

We use PHAsset api to fetch the thumbnail of the iCloud photo ourselves. Customer report that they saw all black photo in Client. Did you encounter the same issue before and did you have any suggestion with this specific issue?
[image]

The codes used to display the UIImage is as following. We use CALayer for displaying the picture.

```
- (void)setImageLayerWithImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    self.imageLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    self.imageLayer.position = CGPointMake(image.size.width/2, image.size.height/2);
    self.imageLayer.contents = (id)image.CGImage;
}
```

The code to fetch thumbnail should be:

```
    - (PHImageRequestID)imageInFullScreen:(MDPhoto *)photoItem
                                       Id:(NSString*)photoID
                               targetSize:(CGSize)targetSize
                        highQualityFormat:(BOOL)highQualityFormat
                                isPreLoad:(BOOL)ispreLoad
                                 saveFile:(BOOL)theSaveFile
                          progressHandler:(PHAssetImageProgressHandler)progressHandler
                        completionHandler:(void (^) (NSDictionary *, NSDictionary *))completionHandler {
        CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
        targetSize = CGSizeMake(targetSize.width * scale, targetSize.height * scale);
        if(targetSize.width < [MDDeviceInfo shareDevice].minImageWidth)
            targetSize = CGSizeMake([MDDeviceInfo shareDevice].minImageWidth, [MDDeviceInfo shareDevice].minImageWidth * targetSize.height/targetSize.width);
        PHImageRequestOptions *options = [self fullScreenRequestOptions:targetSize];
        options.progressHandler = progressHandler;
        MDPhoto* dict = photoItem;
        PHAsset *asset = [(FBYPHAssetWrapper *)[photoItem objectForKey:kFBYAsset] entity];
        if (!asset || [dict[kFBYUploadNeedRefetchAsset] boolValue] || self.isInFullscreenBrowser) {
            FBYPHAssetWrapper *wraper = [FBYAssetManager getAssetWrapperByLocalIdentifier:photoItem[kFBYPHAssetLocalIdentifier]];
            if (wraper) {
                dict[kFBYUploadNeedRefetchAsset]  = @NO;
                [dict setObject:wraper forKey:kFBYAsset];
                asset = [wraper entity];
            }
        }
        if (!asset.localIdentifier) {
            NSLog(@"");
        }
        __block UIImage *aImage = nil;
        
        if(asset.localIdentifier && [[WDPhotoBookManager manager].currentPhotoBook containsAssetIdentifier:[asset.localIdentifier MD5]]){
            NSData* imageData = [[WDPhotoBookManager manager].currentPhotoBook loadImageDataFromIdentifier:[asset.localIdentifier MD5]];
            aImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        }
        
        if (theSaveFile) {
            if (!self.isInFullscreenBrowser) { 
                if (!aImage) {
                    NSString *localIdentifier = photoItem[kFBYPHAssetLocalIdentifier];
                    aImage = [FBYPHAssetHelper mediumSizedImageForAssetID:[FBYGlobal ImagePathWithLocalIdentifier:photoID targetSize:targetSize] pictureDir:[localIdentifier MD5]];
                    if (aImage && !self.isInFullscreenBrowser) {
                        [self drawImage:aImage localIdentifier:[FBYGlobal ImagePathWithLocalIdentifier:photoID targetSize:targetSize]];
                    }
                }
               
            } else {
                options.networkAccessAllowed = YES;
            }
        }
        if (ispreLoad) {
            return 0;
        }
        theSaveFile = YES;
        if (self.isInFullscreenBrowser) {
            aImage = nil;
    //        targetSize = PHImageManagerMaximumSize;
            theSaveFile = NO;
            // WREN-1253
            // iOS: full screen preview shows unnormally
            // Comments: The fetched image is corrupted when using PHImageManagerMaximumSize.
            // So I had to use the explict target size.
            if(IS_SMALL_IPHONE){
            }else {
                targetSize = CGSizeMake(asset.pixelWidth, asset.pixelHeight);
            }
        }
        
        if (self.isInEditPhotoMode) {
            aImage = nil;
            theSaveFile = NO;
        }
        BOOL assetHasBurstIdentifier = asset.burstIdentifier && [asset.burstIdentifier length] > 0;
        
        if (!aImage) {
            if (asset) {
                return [[self class] requestImageForAsset:asset
                                         withImageManager:nil
                                               targetSize:targetSize
                                                  options:options
                                           fixOrientation:YES
                                          representsBurst:asset.representsBurst || assetHasBurstIdentifier
                                                 saveFile:theSaveFile
                                        isInFullScreen:self.isInFullscreenBrowser
                                         isNeedTranparent:YES
                                            resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {
                                                if(!result) {
                                                    NSDictionary* context = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:photoID, @"id",
                                                                             nil];
                                                    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:info];
                                                    [dict addEntriesFromDictionary:info];
                                                    if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
                                                        completionHandler(context, dict);
                                                    } else {
                                                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                            completionHandler(context, dict);
                                                        });
                                                    }
                                                    return ;
                                                }
                                                NSDictionary* context = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                                         result, @"image", photoID, @"id", nil];
                                                if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
                                                    [self checkAndStoreThumbnailCache:result FullScreen:photoItem Id:photoID targetSize:targetSize];
                                                    completionHandler(context, info);
                                                } else {
                                                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                        [self checkAndStoreThumbnailCache:result FullScreen:photoItem Id:photoID targetSize:targetSize];
                                                        completionHandler(context, info);
                                                    });
                                                }
                                                if (!self.isInFullscreenBrowser) {
                                                    [self drawImage:result localIdentifier:[FBYGlobal ImagePathWithLocalIdentifier:photoID
                                                                                                                        targetSize:targetSize]];
                                                }
                                                
                                            }];
            } else {
                NSDictionary* context = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:photoID, @"id",
                                         nil];
                NSDictionary* info = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        photoID, @"id",@"assetMissing",@"error", nil];
                if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
                    completionHandler(context, info);
                } else {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        completionHandler(context, info);
                    });
                }
            }
        } else {
            void (^workToDo) (void) = ^{
                [self checkAndStoreThumbnailCache:aImage FullScreen:photoItem Id:photoID targetSize:targetSize];
                NSDictionary* context = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                         aImage, @"image", photoID, @"id", nil];
                completionHandler(context, nil);
                
            };
            if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
                workToDo();
            } else {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    workToDo();
                });
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code that fetches thumbnails from `PHAsset`s.

Comment: @VadimBelyaev I have upload our codes that fetches thumbnails.